# Application to open .ibk files?

Tags: file-format, software

I have a file with `.ibk` extension. This file should be a book, or a collection of images.

I want to open it,  but I don't know which app is suitable for it!

I tried a lot of apps like:

- ICE Book reader
- vIncrediback
- Inspire windows
- Awave
- Epubor
- Imaging for Windows

but none of them worked with my file!

Does anyone have any idea how to open this file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, or if this is close to an answer, but, according to ChatGPT

> The .ibk file extension is associated with IncrediBackup, a program
> that allows users to back up their IncrediMail email accounts[1]. These
> files store a backup of an IncrediMail account, which includes emails,
> folders, contacts, and other content[1].
>
> To open an .ibk file, you would need the Perion IncrediBackup
> software1. Here are the steps to restore an .ibk file:
>
> Open IncrediBackup. Select “Restore Account.” Choose the account you
> want to restore the account to or select “Restore emails into a new
> account (Recommended).” Click “Next.” Navigate to the location of the
> .ibk file. Select “Open.” Click “OK” to finish1. Please note that you
> should have IncrediBackup installed on your system to open .ibk files.
> If you don’t have it, you may need to install it[2][3][If you’re still
> having trouble, please let me know! I’m here to help.
>
> Learn more 1
>
> fileinfo.com 2
>
> filesuffix.com 3
>
> fileinfo.co 4 datatypes.net